# Angular Js table Formatting based on Year

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, html-table, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am getting response data as:

```
 revenueTableData= [
          {
              "revenueSource": "Customer",
              "revenueYear": "2014",
              "revenueAmount": "5555"
          },
          {
              "revenueSource": "Driver",
              "revenueYear": "2014",
              "revenueAmount": "5555"
          },
          {
              "revenueSource": "Insurance",
              "revenueYear": "2014",
              "revenueAmount": "2300"
          },
          {
              "revenueSource": "Customer",
              "revenueYear": "2015",
              "revenueAmount": "8888"
          },
          {
              "revenueSource": "Driver",
              "revenueYear": "2015",
              "revenueAmount": "1111"
          },
          {
              "revenueSource": "Insurance",
              "revenueYear": "2015",
              "revenueAmount": "6666"
          },
          {
              "revenueSource": "Customer",
              "revenueYear": "2016",
              "revenueAmount": "2222"
          },
          {
              "revenueSource": "Driver",
              "revenueYear": "2016",
              "revenueAmount": "2222"
          },
          {
              "revenueSource": "Insurance",
              "revenueYear": "2016",
              "revenueAmount": "5555"
          }
      ]
```

I wanted to sort revenue amount based on the year and the source:

[image: Like This]

This is what I have tried:

```
 <table>
                  <thead>
                    <tr>
                      <th>
                        <b>&nbsp;</b>
                      </th>
                      <th ng-repeat="i in revenueTableData | unique:'revenueYear' ">{{i.revenueYear}}</th>
                    </tr>
                  </thead>
                  <tbody>
                    <tr ng-repeat="i in revenueTableData | unique :'revenueSource'">
                      <th> {{i.revenueSource}}</th>
                      <td>{{i.revenueAmount}}</td>
                    </tr>
                  </tbody>
                </table>
```

[image: And and displays data like this]

Removing the unique filter will display all the details vertically in the table

I wanted the table in this format

```
<tbody >
                  <tr>
                      <th>Customer</th>
                        <td>Rs.11M</td>
                        <td>Rs.10M</td>
                        <td>Rs.9M</td>
                    </tr>
                  <tr>
                  <th>Insurance</th>
                    <td>Rs.11M</td>
                    <td>Rs.10M</td>
                    <td>Rs.9M</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <th>Franchise</th>
                    <td>Rs.10M</td>
                    <td>Rs.22M</td>
                    <td>Rs.11M</td>
                </tr>


              </tbody>
```

which I'm not able to achieve 
Would really help if someone would help me out
Thanks in advance

**Current JSfiddle** : https://jsfiddle.net/abhishekbhat004/eq75dn9z/1/

Comment: can you make a working code snippet of your code using plunker/jsfiddle/codepen etc. It will be faster to debug your issue

Comment: @VicJordan Here it is https://jsfiddle.net/abhishekbhat004/eq75dn9z/1/
Filter isn't working there. But you get the idea right?
There are to be n rows. In the above data, I'm providing 3
Customer, Driver and Insurace which are having some data for that respective year
In the data that I'm providing there must be only 3 rows and 3 columns